# Will the upgrade from esxi 5.1 to 5.5 preserve host settings?

Tags: vmware-esxi

Specifically network settings, we have it set up so that our hypervisor can see a storage server on the network. Will this need to be reconfigured after the upgrade?

Comment: Have you googled this?  I did and found -> http://www.vmwareandme.com/2013/10/how-to-upgrade-esxi-51-to-55.html#.UotOdNIRDFo - from what it says there, it would appear that nothing is lost in the upgrade process.  Have you checked the esxi 5.5 release notes?

Comment: I have been looking around, in this http://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-55/topic/com.vmware.ICbase/PDF/vsphere-esxi-vcenter-server-55-upgrade-guide.pdf it says that some host settings are lost, but in most of the cases they talk about going from esxi 4 to 5.x, so I'm not sure if this would be the same for going from 5.1 to 5.5. I was hoping that someone would be able to speak from experience.

Comment: I see what you mean in the notes, but it does appear to be 4 to 5 upgrades that will be affected.  Got a good viable backup?

Comment: Yeah, but I'd prefer to know for sure before diving in...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, your settings will be saved in the upgrade from 5.1 to 5.5... But you know you can [save your ESXi host's settings](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=2042141) yourself as well... Insurance.